# Extract string from specific character in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

In My SQL I have String like

```
Declare @Temp Varchar(Max) ='Pravin Gaonkar: 12 Jan 2013 11:56:21 : Hello World 1*Makarand Sawant: 12 Jan 2013 15:36:39 : Hello World 2*Makarand Sawant: 12 Jan 2013 21:21:51 : Hello World 3 *'
```

I have used '*' As Seprator

I want to retrieve Last String from 2nd Last `*` Character to Last `*` Character

in above example the resultant string would be

```
Makarand Sawant: 12 Jan 2013 21:21:51 : Hello World 3
```

MY Query

```
SELECT Reverse(Left(Reverse(@Temp), Charindex('*', Reverse(@Temp)) -1))
```

But it is giving me error **`Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.`**

Database is SQL SERVER 2008

Comment: Do you expect `*` characters after the last one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This assumes no characters after the final `*` and that you have at least 2  `*` overall.

```
SELECT REVERSE(SUBSTRING(LTRIM(Reverse(@Temp)), 2, CHARINDEX('*', @Temp, 2)+1))
```

Personally, I would store this in separate clauses and split it in the client code. Java and .net have far better string handling than SQL Server

Comment: if the string is 'Thakur: 21 Jan 2013 16:14:46 : Cash Is Getting Reversals.*Namdev: 21 Jan 2013 17:41:51 : SLM call logg for ATM not coming inservice Docket No# W301211224  Cust JAGJEET *' Then its not working

Answer (score 1):

Another method: You need one `*` in the middle of the string (where you want to split the string) to use this code.

```
Select replace(Right(yourstring,Len(yourstring) - charindex('*',yourstring)),'*','')
from yourtable
;
```

[SQLFIDDLE DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d8cc6/1)

Results:

```
NEWVALUE
Namdev: 21 Jan 2013 17:41:51 : SLM call logg for ATM not coming
 inservice Docket No# W301211224 Cust JAGJEET
```

Comment: Yes that's the assumption we have taken to arrive at this solution.. There has to be at least one `*` in the middle to sort of simulate the `split`... :) As long as there's one `*` in middle to split the string it works, doesn't really matter if you have a `*` at the end. http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d97bb/1

Comment: Then What about this string --->>   'Thakur: 21 Jan 2013 11:21:27 : Rp Fatal*Singh: 21 Jan 2013 14:17:24 : as per custodian Akshy Ule 844681 engg working at site*Namdev: 21 Jan 2013 16:21:15 : SLM Call logg for RP problenm docket No#317402 *'

Comment: If the String has More than 2 '*' Then also it Fails

Comment: For any efforts that I have spent so far you have even taken away the vote which was there earlier, so how do anyone ever think that further efforts will anyway be appreciated? ( if it was you who took it off....)? You can clearly see my assumption up in the answer., frankly you may put all your test cases in the question and hopefully someone will help you...

Comment: Here is the link if you want to take a look: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2258d/3